# Is there an alternative to point density for rendering with GPU?

Tags: rendering, gpu, point-clouds

Finally working with some clouds. Rendering is horribly slow with my i5 CPU, would be much better with a GTX 970, but if I try that then shaders that use point density no longer work. Is there a good alternative to point density that is renderable with a GPU in Cycles?

Comment: Not really. Point density is pretty unique. You could try to use a particle system on the object (just spawning on the surface, i.e. no actual physics) with various spheres or distorted shapes from displacement maybe, but I've never manages to get it looking quite the same. If you really need point density, I'd anyway recommend using Blender Internal's - yes it is CPU, but goes decently fast, and just requires compositing into your Cycles GPU render in post.

Answer (score 3):

As of version 2.77, Point Density rendering is now supported on GPU. Additional color capabilities should appear in 2.78.

Comment: There is a current bug report (T47794, March 14, 2016) that reports occasional stretching artifacts in a Point Density texture when rendering on GPU.